# Is it possible to prevent parent view from reloading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages, reload

I have two views, one master to the other. There are certain cases when I need the parent view to stay the same while the child view reloads. Is AJAX the only option, or is there another way of doing this?

P.S. Even with the only option being AJAX I'd really appreciate if someone could show the steps to take in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: AJAX is really the only way up updating bits of a page if you don't want to do a page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, only an Ajax call will prevent you from loading the whole page.

Let's say this is your page scheme:

```
<div id="master">
   <div id="section1">
     // use render partial to render this
   </div>

    <div id="section2">
     // use render partial to render this
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to reload a section you can use [JQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to reload only it:

```
$("#section2").load('@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")');
```

Comment: By render partial, do you mean from the controller side, or directly inside the view? I mean, do I render partially in an action method? It'd be awesome if you provided a sample code for action method content too.

Comment: You have a view(lets say a cshtml) where you can render a "sub view". Lets say you have 3 sections in your page. Each one can practically live alone. Create 3 partial views. Read this if what I said sounds new to you: http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/

Answer (score 1):

Using `Ajax` forms is a way I like to do something similar as you can use the UpdateTargetId to render your partial view, and you can easily use the `AntiForgeryToken` features

View:

```
   <div>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", new { id = @Model.MyData }, new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            UpdateTargetId = "renderView"
        }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        }
   </div>

    // This will get populated with the partial
    <div id="renderView" />
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(int id)
    {
       var output = new MyModel{ .....};

       return PartialView(output);
    }
```